# Не выводятся сообщения

Tags: sql

Делаю систему сообщений на сайте, но не получается сделать выборку: Выводятся сообщения и не между пользователями.

```sql
SELECT `id`, `to_id`, `owner_id`, `timestamp_created`, `type`, `text` FROM `messages`
WHERE `owner_id` = :owner_id OR  `to_id` = :to_id OR `owner_id` = :to_id OR `to_id` = :owner_id
```

`to_id` - это id моего адресата
`owner_id` - мой Id

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте один и тот же вопрос не сколько раз

Comment: Неверно сформированный набор условий. Используй `WHERE (:owner_id, :to_id) IN ((owner_id, to_id), (to_id, owner_id))`

Comment: Извините, но данный Вами вариант не работает

Comment: Не работают - негры в африке (извините за мой французский). А запрос либо приводит к сообщению об ошибке (тогда цитируйте его полностью), либо даёт результат, отличающийся от ожидаемого (тогда показывайте исходные данные, точный текст запроса, полученный и ожидаемый выводы).